# Openssl: decrypt using private key, setting oaep

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm trying decrypt a file in openssl that was encrypted with my public key, however I need to use oaep in this proccess. can someone help me  with that?

Answer (score 4):

Provided your key is RSA, you can use `rsautl` command of openssl.

```
openssl rsautl -inkey my_private_key -decrypt -oaep -in my_encrypted_file
```

`rsautl` has the option to support oaep instead (of the default) PKCS#1 v1.5.

Comment: I tried that, and I'm getting a error "rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len".

I tried the 2 commands below:

rsautl -inkey kpri.pem -decrypt -oaep -in tmk_enc.txt /
rsautl -decrypt -inkey kpri.pem -oaep -in tmk_enc.txt -out tmk_dec.txt

I belieave that this file are using SHA 256, I was asking if there is how I decrypt this file using SHA256

Comment: I'm concerned about `tmk_enc.txt`.  `rsautl` is probably expecting a binary, not text.  Is this base64 encoded? if so you will probably need to base64-decode it into a binary file, then use `rsautl`.  (This is also consistent with `rsautl`'s message that you have more data than it was expecting, given your key's modulus size)

Comment: @GeovanneSouza SHA256 is a hashing algorithm, and had nothing to do with encryption/decryption. Now if your cipher text is actually a signature, then use `-verify` instead of `-decrypt` and use your public key.

Comment: The problem is that, when my partner encrypt the same file with my public key, oaep and sha1 I was able to decrypt using this command

Comment: @GeovanneSouza Please update your question with the command you used

Comment: rsautl -decrypt -inkey kpri.pem -oaep -in tmk_encry.txt -out tmk_dec.txt  - I use this command to decrypt the two files, but just worked with the file encrypted with oaep sha1